# how to install SSL certificate on Google cloud VM

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I have purchased a SSL certificate from Godaddy , i have .crt file , .pem file , csr file and private key file
i am having a google cloud VM with a ubuntu OS and hosted API on port 5111

i did attach SSL certificate in my code as mentioned https://timonweb.com/posts/running-expressjs-server-over-https/ in step 2

but still SSL is HTTPS endpoint is not working.

am i missing any steps , any guidance is appreciated here.

Comment: Define "not working". Why's your API running on 5111?

Comment: does need to run on port 443? not working means the API when open in browser says  connection refused

Comment: If you want to access it without typing a port number in the URL, yes.

Comment: ok even changing it to port 443 does not work. am i missing any basic steps . do we need to do anyhting else?

Comment: No clue. You haven't shared your config, you haven't answered what "not working" means exactly, etc.

Comment: what config information do you need?

Comment: Is there a reason you've *twice* now ignored the "define not working" question? **What error or other symptoms are you getting?**

Comment: Hi there. You defined **not working** as a `connection refused` right? Connection refused means that the port is not open. The good news is that the problem seems to be related with your app rather than a FW issue. The bads news is that you need to verify if your app is actually running and listening on the port. Can you please confirm that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a step where we need to upload SSL certificate in App engine settings section and map it with domain